# cursor.moveToFirst()) does not return true

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm stuck into following problem, and I will turn into Hulk, because I could not find any solution yet why my Cursor always returns false?/empty?

Here are (see image) the debug info from cursor, when it does not return true, but why? I think I closed every cursor before - but however it gives me no true :D

cursor.moveToFirst()):

here is the image:

http://postimg.org/image/90y7gexfx/

my code looks like

```
public void doDBStuff(List<Info> list) {

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {.....
```

thank u in advance

Comment: Your image shows, that your cursor has now records. No records = no move to first.

Comment: mCount = 0.  Your table is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cursor.moveToFirst() does not returns true means it is not having any records in that situation only it will returns false.

if you want one method is there in cursor that is getCount(). it will retuns the no of records in the cursor

Comment: does that mean that "   String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE;" return no content?

Comment: that means table is having zero records. if you want one method is there i guess in cursor getCount(). it will retuns the no of records in the cursor.

Comment: hmm - theis weird :S ok... but can it be also that cursor is not closed before?